# vbNewline vs Chr(10) as linebreak delimiter in Windows vs. Mac OSX

Tags: excel, vba, compatibility

I have an Excel sub that uses the `Split()` function to split CSV data from a cell into an array. However, depending on the version of Excel/OS I'm using, the character used as the line break delimiter changes:

Excel 2011 / Mac OSX:

```
 fullArray = Split(CSV, vbNewLine) 'successfully returns array

 fullArray = Split(CSV, Chr(10)) 'fails and returns only a single cell
```

Excel 2007 / Windows 7:

```
  fullArray = Split(CSV, Chr(10)) 'successfully returns array

  fullArray = Split(CSV, vbNewLine) 'fails and returns only a single cell
```

Anyone else noticed this/has an explanation why this is going on?

Comment: Did you not know that the two operating systems have different NewLine characters?

Comment: No, I'm not that familiar with it at all. I just moved to Mac recently. I need this Sub to have good comparability though. Could you point me in the right direction?

Comment: You should be able to successfully use `Environment.NewLine` to get the platform specific new line combination.. assuming Mono implements it correctly (which I assume it does.. ).

Comment: If you need to support multiple OS (or different versions on the same OS) you can look in to conditional compilation statements.

Comment: @SimonWhitehead: it's VBA, not VB.NET

Comment: If the application will be running on one OS and working on files from the other OS, then you need to select which OS the file is from and use either CHR(10) or CHR(13), depending on the file origin.

Comment: @JohnSaunders Ohhhh. I did it again.. apologies. I must remember to ignore the VBA tag :embarassed:

Comment: @DavidZemens, conditional compilation solved it. Could you put your comment in an answer so I can mark this question as solved?

Comment: Sure, give me a minute and I will post it as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to support multiple OS (or different versions on the same OS) you can look in to conditional compilation statements.

You can refer to this list of built-in compiler constants:

http://www.utteraccess.com/wiki/index.php/Conditional_Compilation#Built_In_Compiler_Constants

Define your delimiter variable as a string and assign it the result of a function.

```
Dim dlmt as String

dlmt = newLine()

fullArray = Split(CSV, dlmt)
```

The function then uses the conditional compilation constant to check the OS:

```
Function newLine() As String

#If Win32 Or Win64 Then
    ret = Chr(10)
#ElseIf Mac Then
    ret = vbNewLine
#End If

newLine = ret

End Function
```

Frankly now that I do this I remember it's not strictly necessary to use conditional compile here unless you have methods/properties that won't compile in some versions.  You could use the more simple property of `Application.OperatingSystem`:

```
Function newLine() As String

Select Case Application.OperatingSystem
    Case Like "Windows*" 
        ret = Chr(10)
    Case Else
        ret = vbNewLine
End Select

End Function
```

Comment: Curious who would downvote this without leaving a comment as to *why*, but whatever...

Comment: Probably because of the `Case Like` which is invalid, like it's now [noted below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61986547/11683).

Answer (score 1):

As John mentioned in the comments, the two operating systems have different NewLine character.

And hence before you split it, check for which character is present and then split it. For example

```
newL = InStr(1, CSV, vbNewLine)
vbChrTen = InStr(1, CSV, Chr(10))

If newL > 0 And vbChrTen > 0 Then
    MsgBox "The string contains both. How would you like to handle it?"
    '
    '~~> Rest of the code
    '
ElseIf newL > 0 Then
    fullArray = Split(CSV, vbNewLine)
ElseIf vbChrTen > 0 Then
    fullArray = Split(CSV, Chr(10))
Else
    MsgBox "The string doesn't contain either of the de-limiters. How would you like to handle it?"
    '
    '~~> Rest of the code
    '
End If
```

Comment: I thought `vbNewLine` existed so that you could use it on Mac and Win and it would return the proper line feed for the system you're on. Otherwise what's the point over the other constants `vbLf vbCr vbCrLf`?

Comment: @Dick Kusleika, your correct, but it's not implemented across the board yet in VBA

Answer (score 0):

Case Like "Windows*"  is not valid. 
This works for me:

```
 ' User has Windows or Mac for NewLine
Dim mynewLine As String
If left(Application.OperatingSystem, 7) = "Windows" Then
    mynewLine = Chr(10)
Else
    mynewLine = vbNewLine
End If
```