# VBA check for ENTER character from clipboard

Tags: vba, excel

First of all I have little to no knowledge about VBA.. probably none at all. However I was asked to create a VBA program that paste text from clipboard in different cells. My text has the following format:

```
seminar: name of Seminar (in cell(1,1))
first name: participant's first name (in cell(1,2))
last name: participant's last name (in cell(1,3)) etc..
```

So far I was able to read the text from clipboard. Then I found the position of the ":" in order to paste only what is AFTER it in the cell. 
At this point I thought to find the position of the RETURN character in order to know where the first line ends(ex. "name of Seminar") with this line of code which I found online:

```
end_str = InStr(str, vbCrLf) - 1
```

and with the Right (string, length) function to get the relative text.
This is not working. I think because there are not return character in the string variable that holds the data? I don't know.
My question is: Is it possible to check the RETURN character somehow or Is there a better way to create this program?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy way would be to use the [split](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x627e5f(v=vs.90).aspx) function to get each line separately:

Suppose you have a function called `ClipBoard_GetData` that returns the text from ClipBoard, you could use something like this:

```
Dim lines() As String
lines = Split(ClipBoard_GetData, vbNewLine)
For Each Line In lines
    ' Parse each line to get whatever parts you want
Next
```

This should work fine.. and if you don't -already have a function that gets what's in the clipboard, you could refer to [this link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194373.aspx)

Hope that helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the Ascii code you're after is 10 (ie newline). So you could find the position of the newline like so:

```
i = Instr(str, Chr(10))
```

However, are you aware that you don't need to parse that clipboard text at all. You can write arrays directly into worksheet cells. So all you'd need to do is use the `Split` function. The procedure below will complete everything you need:

```
Public Sub PasteText(str As String)
    Dim arr() As String
    Dim cols As Integer

    arr = Split(str, Chr(10))
    cols = UBound(arr) + 1
    Sheet1.Range("A1").Resize(, cols).Value = arr
End Sub
```

Comment: In Windows, the NewLine is always a carriage return (Cr), followed by a linefeed (Lf) which is equal to `Chr(13) & Chr(10)`.. so using `vbCrLf` or `vbNewLine` is the proper way for splitting by or getting the position of a NewLine

Comment: @GeniuSBraiN yes, I agree ... if the OS is Windows. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26599769/vbnewline-vs-chr10-as-linebreak-delimiter-in-windows-vs-mac-osx