# Excel VBA function to sum all numbers from multi line cell

Tags: vba, excel

Its a cell that can contain multiple line breaks, and the numbers might have decimals

This is what I have been trying, but it just concatenates the numbers, I tried with CDbl instead of VAL and just gives a Value error on the cell

Code:

```
Public Function somaLinhas(str As String)
Dim retorno As Double
retorno = 0
Debug.Print ("Trying to sum : " & str)

For Each lineStr In Split(str, vbNewLine)
    Debug.Print ("line to be added : " & lineStr)

    retorno = retorno + Val(lineStr)
    Debug.Print (retorno)
Next lineStr


If retorno > 0 Then
    somaLinhas = retorno
Else
    somaLinhas = ""
End If


End Function
```

Comment: Try using **`Chr(10)`** instead of **`vbNewLine`**.

Comment: That is not the issue, vbNewLine is the correct constant for line breaks, it is splitting properly, just not adding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following seems to work for me:

```
Public Function somaLinhas(str As String)

Dim retorno As Double
Dim var As Variant
Dim i As Long

retorno = 0
Debug.Print ("Trying to sum : " & str)

var = Split(str, Chr(10))

For i = LBound(var) To UBound(var)
    Debug.Print ("line to be added : " & lineStr)

    retorno = retorno + Val(var(i))
    Debug.Print retorno

Next i

If retorno > 0 Then
    somaLinhas = retorno
Else
    somaLinhas = ""
End If

End Function
```

Comment: It won't work on Mac, and it won't work with decimal separator different than `.`

Comment: As mentioned in the above comment and in the [linked solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26616015/1153513): if you want it to work on a Mac then you should use `vbNewLine`. In respect to your concerns regarding the `Val`[function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264296.aspx) I have to agree. It is rather limited and for better result you might want to consider writing your [own function to convert text to numbers](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/40946-converting-text-number-visual-basic-applications.html).

Comment: I did make a work around with replacing "," s to ".", but not being able to use in a Mac is not an issue