# Why is string search not working?

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement

I am attempting to create an automatically updating worksheet which tracks all the positions of where the text boxes line up in terms of columns. This is to create a gantt chart. basically when i drag the text box it is to tell me what week it is in and every time I change one text box it will update that. The following picture illustrates this well. [image]

The issue is when i keep dragging the text box and change positions over and over again, the weeks dont overwrite the previous week7-week13 but just concatenates the new position ontop of the old one as follows:
[image]
I am trying to write an if statement which basically says that if the substring "week" in in the caption then parse the multi-line textbox into lines and overwrite the first line with the new position. 
This is the code I wrote I just need help with this if statement:

```
Option Explicit
Public alltxt As String
Private selectText() As String

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    UF1.Show
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Target.Parent
    Dim temp
    Dim i
    Dim pos

    Dim shp As Shape
    Dim line As Variant
    For Each shp In ws.Shapes   'loop through all shapes
        If shp.Type = msoTextBox Then 'that are text boxes
            'write the header cells into the text box
            temp = shp.OLEFormat.Object.Caption
            **If InStr(temp, "week")= 0 Then**
                shp.OLEFormat.Object.Caption = ws.Cells(1, shp.TopLeftCell.Column).Text & " - " & ws.Cells(1, shp.BottomRightCell.Column).Text & vbNewLine & shp.OLEFormat.Object.Caption
                Else
                    selectText = Split(shp.OLEFormat.Object.Caption, vbNewLine)
                    selectText(0) = ws.Cells(1, shp.TopLeftCell.Column).Text & " - " & ws.Cells(1, shp.BottomRightCell.Column).Text
                End If

        End If
    Next shp
End Sub
```

Any push in the right direction would be greatly appreciates. And please keep in mind I am relatively new to vba so this may be a really easy fix.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you getting an error? What is the error?

Comment: no error, it runs fine but its as if the if statement is always true but once the box is dragged "week" should be written into the text box and therefore the if statement should be false. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your if condition is fine, but there seems to be an error in the else part

EDIT: The final if condition could be modified to:

```
If InStr(temp, "week")= 0 Then
    shp.OLEFormat.Object.Caption = ws.Cells(1, shp.TopLeftCell.Column).Text & " - " & ws.Cells(1, shp.BottomRightCell.Column).Text & vbNewLine & shp.OLEFormat.Object.Caption
Else
    selectText = Split(shp.OLEFormat.Object.Caption, Chr(10))
    shp.OLEFormat.Object.Caption = ws.Cells(1, shp.TopLeftCell.Column).Text & " - " & ws.Cells(1, shp.BottomRightCell.Column).Text
    for i=1 to UBound(selectText)
        shp.OLEFormat.Object.Caption = shp.OLEFormat.Object.Caption & vbNewLine & selectText(i)
    Next i
End If
```

Care for the OS dependent new line character (See [vbNewline vs Chr(10) as linebreak delimiter in Windows vs. Mac OSX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26599769/vbnewline-vs-chr10-as-linebreak-delimiter-in-windows-vs-mac-osx))

Comment: Thanks for the reply HTh, using selectText(1)  gives me an out of range error.

Comment: so I think were getting close here. The new box updates the first line but doesnt print the other part of the caption. all the textbox says is "week x - week y". I think this is an issue with how we are using the split function because even when we tried selectText(1) it should have worked but it gave me an error of out of range. So I believe the error lies in the split function somehow.

Comment: try "selectText = Split(shp.OLEFormat.Object.Caption, Chr(10)) instead if you are using windows (See [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26599769/vbnewline-vs-chr10-as-linebreak-delimiter-in-windows-vs-mac-osx))

Comment: Ya that did it, Thanks alot. really appreciate you taking the time to help.