# Write function on Excel VBA printing cell value with quotation marks

Tags: excel, vba

I am working on a tablesheet, using VBA for a unique macro function. 
This macro functions allows me to export the values from selected cells in the tablesheet to any folder in my computer.

```
Dim myFile As String, rng As Range, cellValue As Variant, i As Integer, j As Integer
    myFile = "C:\Users\caique.fernandes\Desktop\" & "\NumeroChamados.txt"
    Set rng = Selection
    Open myFile For Output As #1
    
    For i = 1 To rng.Rows.Count
        For j = 1 To rng.Columns.Count
        cellValue = rng.Cells(i, j).Value2
        If j = rng.Columns.Count Then

            Write #1, cellValue
        Else
            Write #1, cellValue,
        End If
        
            Next j
        Next i
        
        Close #1
End Sub
```

There's a column that the values are like `000001`, `000002`, etc. When I select it to export the values on a `.txt file`, it exports the values like `"000001"` but I need only the numbers. I have already tried put single quotes at the beginning of the cell, change the code for `Print` intead of `Write` and also changed the cell type for text/number/general, but it continues to exporting the value with quotation marks.

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Ps. All others columns that I have with numbers are prices and dates, and the format for this one have to be like `000001`.

Comment: `Write #1` and `Print #1` do different things.  `Print` does not include quotes (I know you tried that, but I would try again...).  FYI your file path has two consecutive `\` - `C:\Users\caique.fernandes\Desktop\\NumeroChamados.txt`

Comment: I prefer to use the `FileSystemObject` for reading and writing. It's newer and much nicer than the old VB methods you are using.
https://analystcave.com/vba-filesystemobject-fso-in-excel/vba-opentextfile/

Comment: The file path was ok, even with the extra \.. And I just tried with `Print` but I have other columns that needs the quotation marks.. Its specifically that with `000001` format

Comment: Are the cells with `000001` etc formatted as Text?

Comment: I ran your code with `Print` and with the `00001` etc values formatted as text and it worked fine - no quotes in any column.

Comment: With the text format it prints this: "000001"
With the number format it prints this: 1
With the custom format (000000) it prints this: 1

Comment: I know that with `print` works fine, but like I said, I need the quotation marks on other columns.. and with `print`, it removes all the quotations marks AND the commas..

Comment: You did not actually specify you needed the quotes on the other columns - if that's the case then you will need to use Print and add the quotes "manually" according to the specific column being output.

Answer (score 0):

If you need more control over how certain columns are output then you can do something like this:

```vb
Sub Tester()
    Dim myFile As String, rng As Range, i As Long, j As Long
    Dim qt As String, lf As String, sep As String, ln As String
    myFile = "C:\Tester\NumeroChamados.txt"
    Set rng = Selection
    Open myFile For Output As #1
    
    For i = 1 To rng.Rows.Count
        ln = ""
        sep = ""
        For j = 1 To rng.Columns.Count
            
            qt = IIf(j = 1 And i > 1, """", "")         'adding quotes? e.g. Col1 only
            lf = IIf(j = rng.Columns.Count, vbCrLf, "") 'end of line?
            
            ln = ln & sep & qt & rng.Cells(i, j).Value2 & qt & lf
            
            sep = vbTab  'add separator after first value is written
            
        Next j
        Print #1, ln
    Next i
        
    Close #1
End Sub
```

If you need cross-platform support then check out: [vbNewline vs Chr(10) as linebreak delimiter in Windows vs. Mac OSX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26599769/vbnewline-vs-chr10-as-linebreak-delimiter-in-windows-vs-mac-osx)